# Creating field indicating if two layers intersect

Tags: qgis, layers, intersection, overlapping-features

I have the similar problem to this question but in QGIS: [Create a field indicating if the polyline intersects the shapefile boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228985/create-a-field-indicating-if-the-polyline-intersects-the-shapefile-boundaries)

I want to select the areas intersecting with the layer `station_300m` I used this expression:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry('station_300m_5142f160_96d1_491b_836f_9bc56c884a03'))
```

and I got this error message
[image: error_message]

I also tried this expression:

```
intersects($geometry,geometry(get_feature('station_300m_5142f160_96d1_491b_836f_9bc56c884a03')))
```

but it also didn't work. What goes wrong in my expression?

I'm using QGIS version 3.16.6-Hannover.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use the `select by location` tool instead of `select by expression`.

Answer (score 7):

**What went wrong and how to use the expression**

The function `intersects(geometry1,geometry2)` expects two geometries as arguments. Your second argument is **not** a geometry. You try to convert a layer to a geometry in your first expression. That doesent work, as `geometry()` expects a feature, not a layer as input.

Your second approach adresses this, using a `get_feature()` statement. However, the syntax of get_feature is `get_feature(layer,attribute,value)`, but you have specified only the layer.

**How to solve the problem**

1. Use the solution by @Erik.
2. Add the correct arguments in the second of your expressions as stated above.
3. As you use QGIS 3.16, you can use `overlay_intersects('station')`. The [overlay-functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_intersects#overlay-intersects) were introduced in QGIS 3.16.

Comment: Just wanted to add the bit on `overlay_intersects` ;-)

Comment: So our two intentions intersected ;-)